# Facebook with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ssh, facebook, tunnel, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to follow the [Facebooker tutorial](http://www.nolanconsul.com/articles/facebooker-tutorial/) (for Ruby on Rails) but I can't get the ssh tunnel running:

> Bring up your terminal again. You need to start your local development server, and then make that server available to the wider internet. Do this like so:

```
script/server &  
rake facebooker:tunnel:start &
```

> Once your server has started, the second command will start a reverse ssh tunnel.

When I execute the second command, I get the following:

```
user@computer:~/facebooker-test$ rake -t facebooker:tunnel:start 
(in /home/user/facebooker-test)  
** Invoke facebooker:tunnel:start (first_time)  
** Invoke environment (first_time)  
** Execute environment  
** Invoke facebooker:tunnel:config (first_time)  
** Invoke environment  
** Execute facebooker:tunnel:config
** Execute facebooker:tunnel:start
Starting tunnel :4007 to 0.0.0.0:3000
OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-6ubuntu2, OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxY] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile]
           [-i identity_file] [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] [user@]hostname [command]
user@computer:~/facebooker-test$
```

Apparently, there's some sort of incompatibility between the `rake` task's `ssh` command, and the correct syntax.

I'm using Ubuntu 9.10 with the `openssh-server` package, and the facebooker plugin for Ruby on Rails out-of-the-box from github.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, I've figured it out.
Apparently, I was missing some definitions in my `facebooker.yml` file.

I had to put in the host and usernam.

I discovered this by going into `vendor/plugins/facebooker/lib/tasks/tunnel.rake` and putting adding the following line to the end of the `:config` directive:

```
@notification <<"using the following ssh command: \n #{@ssh_command}"
```

Then, when I call rake with -t option, I get an output of how the command will be executed.
I saw a trailing `@` at the end of the command, and realized what was missing.
Yay me!

Comment: Yay you! *15 chars*